# convert pixel coordinates to lat long

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I would like to understand how the geo referencing for images works.
Is there some way how to get the real langitude and longitude from this line?

```
imageBounds = [map.unproject([0, 0], 20), map.unproject([1716,1178], 20)];
```

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

`map.unproject([xy coords])` returns a `Latlng` object.  Try running the function in the console or wherever and you'll see your lat and lng?